# Badly Conditioned Matrix Error - Should I concern myself with it?

Tags: numerical-methods, condition-number

I have a 16 by 16 matrix A with increasing powers in each row, and a vector b. When I try to use Mathematica to solve Ax=b (using LinearSolve) I get an error warning me there may be significant numerical errors because of badly conditioned matrix.

I don't quite understand this notion, but I am under the impression that it just means it is a very "sensitive" equation, so an error in A or B may cause significant errors in x. Given that A and b have integer components that I have not rounded, is this something to be concerned? Does the algorithm or rounding Mathematica does with LinearSolve affect this?

EDIT:

I am unable to post the code right now, will do so later. What confuses me is this (in wikipedia: Condition Number): "For example, the condition number associated with the linear equation Ax = b gives a bound on how inaccurate the solution x will be after approximation. Note that this is before the effects of round-off error are taken into account; conditioning is a property of the matrix, not the algorithm or floating-point accuracy of the computer used to solve the corresponding system. In particular, one should think of the condition number as being (very roughly) the rate at which the solution x will change with respect to a change in b. Thus, if the condition number is large, even a small error in b may cause a large error in x. On the other hand, if the condition number is small, then the error in x will not be much bigger than the error in b.". If A and b are exact, why does condition number matter?

Comment: The errors occur during the algorithm and get amplified by the underlying instability of the system. Not rounding the entries doesn't really shield you from it. In principle you could get an exact solution with full rational number arithmetic but that can get pretty expensive even in relatively small problems.

Comment: When the determinant of a matrix is small, or even if there is some direction such that $Ax=\epsilon x$ with $\epsilon$ small, then the errors in $x=A^{-1}b$ could be large. See [Condition Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number#Matrices).

Comment: If you're using Mathematica, then input the numbers as ```34``` not as ```34.``` i.e. as integers not as reals. It should avoid the problem.

Comment: I am unable to post the code right now, will do so later. I added an update to my post, after seeing your answers.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, doing Inverse[A].b instead of LinearSolve[A,b] didn't yield this error, so I believe it solves the problem in my case.